# How to include additional select statement in a JOIN? PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables with data like:

**tagmap**

```
===============
 item | tagid
---------------
 1111 |   101
 1111 |   102
 2222 |   101
 2222 |   103
 3333 |   104
 4444 |   105
 4444 |   106
 5555 |   101
 5555 |   103
==============
```

item + tagid = composite primary key

**flavors**

```
===============
 id  | flavor
---------------
 101 | flavorA
 102 | flavorB
 103 | flavorC
 104 | flavorD
 105 | flavorE
 106 | flavorF
===============
```

id = primary key

I run PHP + MySQL. I have a query like;

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(a.tagid ORDER BY a.tagid) tags
  FROM tagmap a
  JOIN tagmap b
    ON b.item = a.item
   AND b.tagid <= a.tagid
 WHERE b.tagid = '101'
 GROUP
    BY a.item;
```

I store this to a variable `$query` which returns me data like;

```
flavorA,flavorB
flavorA,flavorC
```

In PHP, i use

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tag = $rowa['tags'];
    echo $tag."<br>";
}
```

code to print the result. But along with this, I want the flavor ids, an I want to store then to another variable like;

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tag = $rowa['tags'];
    $tagid = $rowa['tagid'];//what I am looking for.
    echo $tag."<br>";//echoes flavorA,flavorB
    echo $tagid."<br>";//want to echo 101,102
}
```

In every `foreach` loop, I want to store `id`s as CSV in one variable and `flavor`s as CSV in another variable. For example, when it return `flavorA,flavorB`, I want to store it in `$tag` (already doing) and `101,102` in `$tagid` (what I want in additional).

How can I do this? I mean, where to / how to include the `select flavor` statement and how to fetch it?

Comment: @Strawberry, but that situation returns `id`s alone.. Now I need both, the names and IDs.. Hope you understand...

Comment: @Strawberry could you post it as answer pls..

Comment: so where do I use select names and ids statement? is it like `SELECT id  DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(a.tagid ORDER BY a.tagid) tags` ??

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer your question...

```
SELECT t.item
     , f.flavor 
  FROM tagmap t 
  JOIN flavors f 
    ON f.id = t.tagid;
+------+---------+
| item | flavor  |
+------+---------+
| 1111 | flavorA |
| 1111 | flavorB |
| 2222 | flavorA |
| 2222 | flavorC |
| 3333 | flavorD |
| 4444 | flavorE |
| 4444 | flavorF |
| 5555 | flavorA |
| 5555 | flavorC |
+------+---------+
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want something like `flavorA,flavorB,101,102` in a single row. I want to store `flavorA,flavorB` in a variable and `101,102` in another variable.

Comment: added more detail to question

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ You would do that in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Simply include two `GROUP_CONCAT()` columns, grouped by `ITEM` in SQL query. And if needed to get a distinct resultset, set it up inside a derived table subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tagids, flavors    
FROM
   ( SELECT t.item,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tagid ORDER BY t.tagid) AS tagids,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.flavor ORDER BY f.flavor) AS flavors
     FROM tagmap t 
     INNER JOIN flavors f ON f.id = t.tagid
     GROUP BY t.item
   ) As grptbl
```

SQL OUTPUT

```
tagids     flavors
101,102    flavorA,flavorB
101,103    flavorA,flavorC
104        flavorD
105,106    flavorE,flavorF
```

Then have PHP reference the `tagids` and `flavors` columns in associative array. **NOTE**: I use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) over the deprecated (now discontinued in PHP 7) mysql_* function.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if ($result) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       echo $row['flavors']."<br>"; //echoes flavorA,flavorB
       echo $row['tagids']"<br>";   //echoes 101,102
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: the code shows `flavorA,flavorC` twice. I want it to appear once only, skipping redundant rows.

Comment: See update where a derived table is used to return distinct records.